# How to start drawing a path immediately after setting the canvas to drawing mode in FabricJS?

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to detect if an object has been selected on a mouse down event, and if no object was selected to start drawing in fabric. As such I can't leave the canvas in drawing mode, but need to set it once I have determined that the mouse down event had no target. At the moment I've tried retriggering the mouse down event on the canvas a la:

```
this.canvas.on('mouse:down', function (e) {
        if(e.target === null){ //the event had no target
            this.isDrawingMode = true; //set the canvas to drawing mode
            this.trigger('mouse:down'); //retrigger mouse down event
    }});
```

but I'm not that lucky. The event is retriggered but a path doesn't begin drawing on the canvas. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the function that would be called by fabric if you were in drawingmode before mouse down.

Be aware of the if condition i inserted `!this.isDrawingMode` or you get an infinite loop of recursion.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({width: 50, height: 50}));
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(opt) {
  if (!opt.target && !this.isDrawingMode) {
    canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
    canvas._onMouseDownInDrawingMode(opt.e)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.18/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" ></canvas>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help! This is a handy trick for 'picking up' objects you've just added to a canvas too!